# Create never ending hot stream in spring flux

Tags: java, events, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a consumer that serves data. Data is consumed and processed - not reactive. Then I took this data and send it to:

```
Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```

I am using

```
sink.emitNext(
    message, retryOn(Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST, message));
```

as suggested in other stack posts, where I am taking care of

```
Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED
```

Still stuck on reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Backpressure overflow during Sinks.Many#emitNext

On the front end there is subscriber EventSource. My GET endpoint (simplified, tried many things here)

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Message>> streamData() {
    return service
        .getSink()
        .asFlux()
        .map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e).event(e.getType().getId()).build());
  }
```

I have tried suggestions in other posts. But I am obviously not capable to do: Never ending hot event stream, in which the subscriber once connected never misses any message.

Code is welcome, but opinions more matters.

Recap: Never ending hot event source, no message is lost to subscriber.

EDIT: Why the suggested posts don work for me: I am missing the part between the Consumer(of the queue) - Sink - Get endpoint: still end with reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Backpressure overflow during Sinks.Many#emitNext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A consumer receives data from queue. Data is processed non reactive. Result data sent to... Should be received in EventSource in front end.

Used sink to send the processed data:

```
sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directAllOrNothing();
```

```
sink.emitNext(
   ServerSentEvent.builder(message).event(message.getType().getId()).build(),
   retryOnNonSerialized(Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST,message)
);
```

Controller:

```
@PostConstruct
private void loadFlux() {
   log.info("Constructing Flux....");
   flux = service
      .getSink()
      .asFlux()
      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      .onBackpressureBuffer()
      .onBackpressureDrop(message -> blog.debug("[STREAM] Backpressure message drop: {}", message))
      .share();
}
```

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Message>> streamData() {
   return fluxData;
}
```

Works for me for never ending hot stream.